# How to set a controller's content property to an array of models without a corresponding route?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm using the {{render}} handlebars helper in one of my templates to (attempt to) render the template of another route on the same page. So for example:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

{{#each model}}
  {{name}}<br />
{{/each}}

{{render "people"}}

</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="people">

{{#each controller}}
  {{name}}<br />
{{/each}}

</script>
```

In my people controller I set the model as usual:

```
App.PeopleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.People.find();
  }
});
```

If I visit my people route directly (/people), I get a list of people. In my main template where the people template is being rendered into another template, the render helper doesn't call the PeopleRoute, so the model is never set (as far as I understand it).

Is there a way for me to set the content property on the PeopleController to the list of people objects?

I can't get any variation of this to work:

```
App.PeopleController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  content: function() {
    return App.People.find();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The render helper doesnt make any transitions and hence the model hook will not get called.. It just renders the template in the current context with the same-named controller... You can pass an optional model to the render helper which binds to the content of the same-named controller... [Ember API](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_render)

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">

   {{#each model}}
    {{name}}<br />
   {{/each}}

    {{render "people" model}} 

   </script>
```

Sample fiddle [here](http://jsbin.com/ikijoq/7/edit)

Comment: Hi Selva, I know you can pass another argument to the render helper, but the value I'm trying to pass isn't available in the current template either.

Comment: What are you trying to pass indeed?